# обновить БД на Azure Asp Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure

Я изменил модель **MyModel** добавив в нее новое свойство **Myprop{get; set;}**

теперь когда я публикую изменения на Azure я получаю ошибку: "sql Exception... не правильное имя столбца Myprop ".

Нужно видимо как то применить миграции и обновить бд на Azure.

Тогда в настройках publish я выбираю следующий пункт  "Apply this migrations on publish" (я решил что это то что мне нужно.)

Публикую и получаю новую ошибку: "There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database." - это какой то баг в Core. Эта же ошибка была когда я только начал проект, [и решит ее удалось только создав новую бд](https://petermcintyre.com/topics/already-object-named-aspnetroles/)  . Но это бред какой то, к тому же данные должны сохранится.

Как решить эту проблему?

PS: на локальной машине все работает. И касательно второй ошибка отгуглил все вдоль и поперек, так что новая бд это единственное решение что у меня заработало.

Comment: А у вас разные что ли базы - одна для разработки, а др. для продакшена? Иначе не понятно почему миграции сразу не применяются, а только в момент публикации.

Comment: Да, так получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно на портале azure зайти в панель управления базой данных. Затем в "Редактор запросов" и написать запрос на добавление столбца

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD PropName PropType
```

тогда заработает, если нет то перезагрузить приложение. И отключить "Apply this migrations on publish" - если это приводит к ошибке.